# Mobile Safari width issue

Tags: html, css, css-float, mobile-safari

I have this weird issue on mobile safari (tested on iPad and iPhones), the body and some divs are cut off in the middle and I can do nothing about it. It works fine on desktop, but not on mobile safari. Here is a link: [http:pinsupreme.com](http://pinsupreme.com)
and a screenshot from iphone: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this as viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: This does not work either. It now adds a scrollbar and zooms in to the cut off area.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by setting a **meta viewport** to **width=1200**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200" />
```